# It's possible to hide the grunt-contrib-watch log?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch, grunt-concurrent

Using the [grunt-contrib-watch](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch) with [grunt-concurrent](https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-concurrent) I want to hide/ignore **only the watch log** when one or more files are changed.

Something like this:

```
>> File "karma/lcov-report/login/Login.js.html" changed.
>> File "karma/lcov-report/login/index.html" changed.
```

It's possible?

My concurrent grunt config:

```
    concurrent: {
        options: {
            logConcurrentOutput: true
        },
        karma: {
            tasks: ["karma:dev", "watch:karma"]
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is no relevant option in the `grunt-watch` options, you could try [`grunt-verbosity`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-verbosity).

Comment: I have already tried but the grunt-verbosity don't execute the watch with livereload